# Automate deploy of Machine Key in a shared config IIS

Tags: azure-devops, web-config, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, web.config-transform

I'm using Azure DevOps to deploy an ASP.NET application to an IIS servers on-prem.  The IIS servers are using a shared configuration so they need a custom Machine Key setup.

I can use XML transform to add add the machineKey entry in the Web.Config

```
  <system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="{hex-key value}" validationKey="{hex-key value}"/>
  </system.web>
```

but I don't want to have the actual keys in source control so I'll need to replace those values at deploy time.  Substitution is easy enough for appsettings and connection strings but how can I substitute values in the System.Web section of the Web.Config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I substitute values in the System.Web section of the
>   Web.Config?

What about consider to use one extension [Replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)? For why I recommend it is because it can achieve the demand that it can only be replaced during the pipeline running.

Also, its usage is very convenient. Just need to specify the `prefix` and `suffix` in the task, and then make apply them in to your `web.config` file.

[image]

Then specify the corresponding variables with same name in **Variables** tab.

Only this, during the pipeline running, the task could find the corresponding token correctly and replace the value into it.

For detailed steps, you could refer to my previous answer for details: [Use replace token task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877200/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-group-in-jmeter-using-azure-pipeline/57887868#57887868).

Comment: So then in my web.config I'd have an entry like this:
 

`<machineKey decryptionKey="#{decryptionKey}#" validationKey="#{validationKey}#" />`


that get's deployed from a pipeline that has variables like this?


`Name:  decryptionKey
Value:   170C6CD9055AnotarealkeyDEE5D01C93F5A08B7E7E2AECE4CE4


Name:  validationKey
Value:   562BF31C1F78028FD9335notarealkey7249EF3BE71A57D50BC1CCE70ADD1932F7C9B7667963E531000DABD650E452E02EB18B8508DDB3DA191E70EB`