# Azure Pipelines Release XML Variable Substitution skipped

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this web.config file i place in the root of my project that is built by azure devops here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ManagementStudio.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="MS_CONNECTIONSTRING" value="" />
          <environmentVariable name="CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS" value="" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="" />
          <environmentVariable name="MS_COOKIEEXPIRYTIMEINMINUTES" value="" />
          <environmentVariable name="MS_STATICFILECACHEINSECONDS" value="" />
          <environmentVariable name="MS_COOKIEDOMAIN" value="" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I then set these bunch of variables in the release section:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
Development
CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS
csa
CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN
csd
MS_CONNECTIONSTRING
connstring
MS_COOKIEDOMAIN
dev.website.com
```

I set them as settable at release time.

In my IIS Web App Deploy, I ticked XML Variable Substitution.

However, it doesn't seem like any of my variables are changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reason of why it does not be applied successfully, I agree with Troopers.

But, it does not mean you could not use environment variable anymore. If `environment variable` is the preferred choice you want, you can consider to use [replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task to achieve what you want.

For detailed used about this task, you can refer to my previous [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877200/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-group-in-jmeter-using-azure-pipeline/57887868#57887868).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Where do I use replace token? I tried using it in the Build but it keeps saying that it skips updating my file?

Comment: @JianYA, of course do this replacement before you use the config. Mostly, I did this before the repos was build. For skipping issue, did you target the config in the task definition? Also, you need do some configuration in your config file (#{parameter name}#) so that it can replaced by your environment variable.

Comment: Hello, I am trying it again now. Does that mean that my web.config files should have something like (#{parameter name}#) in the value?

Comment: @JianYA. Yes, only this, the replace token task can found corresponding location to replace value. This is the disadvantage of this method if it has any disturb.

Answer (score 1):

Only the section `appSettings`, `connectionStrings` and `applicationSettings` are substitued ([see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution)), and section must contain configuration element with `key` or `name` like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

where you can define a variable `MyDB` to set the connection string

**--Update--**

For `environmentVariables` section you could test this suggestion from the documentation :

> If you are looking to substitute values outside of these elements you
>   can use a (parameters.xml) file, however you will need to use a 3rd
>   party pipeline task to handle the variable substitution.

Comment: So I won't be able to use environmentVariables at all?